# How to convert JSON string to a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a Json object that being received in PHP as a string.... not object - i want to convert it to an PHP array, now, i could create a function that strips  the string and removing the brackets... position all the keys and the values in their position... but i wonder if maybe there is a better way...

The json string is being printed.... so that's why it's comes as a string

```
 <?php
    $foo =json_decode('<ion:images/>'); // IonizeCms tag

    // $foo[0] will output "{"...and not "cat"....
  ?>

 // {"name":cat,"pic":"cat.png"}{"name":dog,"pic":"dog.png",}
```

I'm using [Ionize](http://doc.ionizecms.com/) framework - which is based upon codeigniter - so here is the tag that creates the images tag :

```
     public static function tag_images(FTL_Binding $tag)
      {

     $str = '';

    // Model load
     self::load_model('page_test_model');

     $new_details = self::$ci->page_test_model->get_details();

     foreach ($new_details as $image) {

        if(is_array($image)){

            $str .=json_encode($image, true);

        }

       }

    return json_encode($str, true);
   }
```

As requested in the comments:

```
var_dump(json_decode('<ion:images/>'));
var_dump(json_last_error_msg());
```

will give - in the view (not in source code)

```
string(104) "{"name":"cat,"pic":"cat.png"}{"name":"dog","pic":"dog.png"}‌​" 
string(8) "No error"
```

[image]

Comment: What your're decoding in your example doesn't look like Json it looks like XML

Comment: Thanks..I'm using ionizecms - it's slimier to wordpress - but crappier... so i need the extract data  from the tags.... so <ion:test_images/> will output an array - but tags cannot handle array.. so i decode the tag to get it's content...and that's why it's appears as a string

Comment: yes. that's right. than you need to go to regular expresion and parse that string on your own. Or find out how to use that tags in controllers

Comment: Ah wait, I know what's wrong. Instead of `var_dump(json_decode('<ion:images/>'));` please try without the single quotes, e.g. `var_dump(json_decode(<ion:images/>));`. That will then probably give you the expected NULL/Syntax Error combination.

Comment: Gordon - yeah..it's return NULL and the syntax seems to be wrong...

Comment: Commited an answer. Took me a while to figure out a solution to this. Seemed easier but...

Comment: if remove the foreach completely and have the function `return json_encode($new_details, true);` - what does that do then?

Comment: Got it.....we've going around the bush - but the solution was to just add coma between the string..... check out the answer

Comment: On a side note: is there any reason why you are encoding this to JSON in the tag only to decode it then in the View? Why are you not just returning the array?

Comment: Thanks Gordon - i've tried it also - tags cannot output array.. wish they do...

Comment: Thanks bud - works - saved me a whole lot of redundant code - thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` expects a valid JSON string for input. Your input is not a JSON string. Your input is an XML element. When you try to `json_decode` something that is not a JSON string, the decoding will fail.

```
$foo = json_decode('<ion:test_images/>');

var_dump($foo); // NULL
var_dump(json_last_error_msg()); // "Syntax error"
```

See http://eval.in/905948

Ionize apparently evals the tag prior to `json_decode` getting executed, but since you wrapped the element in single quotes, json_decode will just treat the input as a string. So you'd need to use

```
$foo = json_decode(<ion:test_images/>);
```

However, the JSON produced from the tag is invalid, too:

```
{"name":cat,"pic":"cat.png"}{"name":dog,"pic":"dog.png",}
```

would need to be

```
[{"name":"cat","pic":"cat.png"},{"name":"dog","pic":"dog.png"}]
```

So make sure to pass valid JSON, e.g. fix the code that produces the JSON:

```
 public static function tag_images(FTL_Binding $tag)
 {
     $images = array();
     self::load_model('page_test_model');
     $new_details = self::$ci->page_test_model->get_details();

     foreach ($new_details as $image) {
         if (is_array($image)){
             $images[] = $image;
         }
     }

     return json_encode($images, true);
}
```

Previously, you'd `json_encode` the images to string and then `json_encode` that string again. That obviously won't produce a collection then, but just concatenated single objects or arrays.

Comment: Thanks - the function that responsible for <ion:test_images/> is returning json... i guess as you said...it's being output the string... so is it possible to convert the string to php array in a simple way? other then custom function...

Comment: @RoyBarOn you will need to use the function directly as the input to `json_decode`. Not the tag.

Comment: thanks - but i can't pull any variables to views without using tags..... this is way i've done json_decode('<ion:images/>') = for get the tag's data into variable...

Comment: @RoyBarOn **again:** unless Ionize evals the tag prior to `json_decode` getting executed, this will never work.

Comment: Gordon , thanks,  perhaps i could parse some how the string after it's executed in the view ?   perhaps there is a method the takes a structure of a string and parse it accordingly?

Comment: @RoyBarOn I'd prefer you fix the JSON output of that tag instead. Is this a custom tag. Can you modify it so it returns valid JSON?

Comment: Gordon - thanks - i've tried to do so for the last 2 days.... but couldn't figure it out.... so that's why i'm trying to parse the result of the tag.... after it's being executed... the structure of the framework is codeigniter... so first i've tried to send the data directly from the controller - but  since ionize is parsing the views also , so it cannot be done...

Comment: @RoyBarOn I am not familiar with Ionize. Can you provide the code that replaces the tag? Fixing the JSON after it was produced will be much harder.

Answer (score 2):

as you can see in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

use second parameter of json_decode

```
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Comment: while setting the second argument to true would create an array structure, it still depends on the input string being actually valid json. Which it isn't.

Comment: This is not a json object to decode it like that, it is not even a valid json.

Comment: No comment on posters intention - but not sure how something gets upvoted which blatantly won't work?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data='{"name":cat,"pic":"cat.png"}{"name":dog,"pic":"dog.png",}'; //the input string
$data = str_replace(array('{','}',':',','), '',$data); //replacing in order to prepare my explode to convert it into a normal array
$data=explode('"',$data); //first array creation
$data =  array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $data), 'strlen'));//remove some empty fields that were caused from explode to keep only the values needed and re-arrange array keys
//print_r($data);
$newArray=array();
$arrayKeys=array();
$arrayFields=array();

for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i=$i+2){
    $arrayKeys[$i]=$data[$i];
}
for($i=1;$i<count($data);$i=$i+2){
    $arrayFields[$i]=$data[$i];
}


$arrayKeys =  array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $arrayKeys), 'strlen'));

$arrayFields =  array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $arrayFields), 'strlen'));
$counter=0;

//setting up the fields and filling with values (they need to be nested because an array can not have duplicate keys)
for($i=0;$i<count($arrayKeys);$i++){
    $newArray[$i]['name']=$arrayFields[$i];
    $i++;
    $newArray[$i]['pic']=$arrayFields[$i+$counter];
}

//fixing array format
for($i=0;$i<count($newArray);$i=$i+2){
    $newArray[$i]=array_merge($newArray[$i],$newArray[$i+1]);
    unset($newArray[$i+1]);
}
echo'<pre>';

print_r($newArray);
```

That was more tricky that i thought but finally it's done!!! i have added comments in my code so it can be understandable.

The output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => cat
            [pic] => cat.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => dog
            [pic] => dog.png
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort - but i was looking for more simple  way - thanks again!

Comment: I wish i could use json_decode but your string is not a valid json so i had to find another way to provide the array.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... since the string was malformed so it cannot be decoded as JSON , so

this 
{"name":cat,"pic":"cat.png"}{"name":dog,"pic":"dog.png",}

was suppose to looks like

{"name":cat,"pic":"cat.png"}**,**{"name":dog,"pic":"dog.png"} // with comma between

And the result

```
 <?php
  $images_arr =json_decode('<ion:images/>');

   $finale_arr=[];
   $images_arr = str_replace("}{","}||{",$images_arr);
   $images_arr = explode("||",$images_arr);

   foreach ($images_arr as $image_arr){

   $finale_arr[]=json_decode($image_arr);

    }

      $array = json_decode(json_encode($finale_arr), 
      True);

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($array);
   echo '</pre>';
  ?>


 //Outputs
 Array
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => cat
        [pic] => cat.png

      )

   [1] => Array
     (
        [name] => dog
        [pic] => dog.png
    )

  )
```

Comment: that is horrible. please do yourself a favor and just fix the tag producing code. I've updated my answer with the solution on how to do that.

Comment: I agree... that's what i've tried to avoid - hang on - i'll test your solution